# How to reset system proxy in CentOS using python code

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I am using the following python code (Python 2.7) to reset the proxy of (Cent OS 6) system, but I am unable to reset the proxy:

Code:

```
     import os 
     print "Unsetting http..." 
     os.system("unset http_proxy") 
     os.system("echo $http_proxy") 
     print "http is reset"
```

Output:

```
    Unsetting http...
    http://web-proxy.xxxx.xxxxxxx.net:8080
    http is reset
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

It should not return `http://web-proxy.xxxx.xxxxxxx.net:8080` in output.

I run the same unset command from the terminal, then I see that proxy is reset:

```
[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$ unset $HTTP_PROXY
[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$ echo $HTTP_PROXY

[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$
```

Please suggest how to reset system proxy using Python Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "proxy_detail"
```

`os` module has properties to set environment variables. Put value in string(double/single quotes)